# XML parsing special characters: Excel VBA Run time error 91

Tags: php, xml, excel, xml-parsing, vba

When XML parsing special characters - my specific issue is with ampersands -  Excel VBA is throwing the error

> Run time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

PHP code for XML Parsing:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root> <EngineerFName>'.$engineer_fname.'</EngineerFName>
<CustomerName>'.$customer_name.'</CustomerName>
<EngineerLName>'.$engineer_lname.'</EngineerLName>
<TopName>'.$dt_top_name.'</TopName>  
</root>';
```

Excel Vba code:

```
Dim XDoc1 As Object
Dim XHTML1 As IHTMLElement
Dim XURL1 As String
Dim CustomerName1 As String
Set XDoc1 = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
XDoc1.async = False: XDoc1.validateOnParse = False
XDoc1.Load ("http://www.beamon.com/windows_application/macro2.php" +  "?Id=" + Sheets(1).Range("D2"))
Set lists = XDoc1.DocumentElement
Set getFirstChild = lists.FirstChild
Set getCustomerName1 = lists.ChildNodes(1)
Set getEnglname = lists.ChildNodes(2)
Set getTopCustomer = lists.ChildNodes(3)

Sheets(1).Range("T5") = getCustomerName1.text
Sheets(1).Range("T6") = getFirstChild.text & Space(1) & getEnglname.text
Sheets(1).Range("T7") = getTopCustomer.text
Set XDoc1 = Nothing
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Which line causes your error?

Comment: In Excel Vba code 9th line "Set getFirstChild = lists.FirstChild"  is causing "Run time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: The above VBA code runs without error, so your problem cannot be reproduced. We would need to know which id you were trying to use (`Sheets(1).Range("D2")`), and even then it's likely a problem with that rather than the code.

Comment: yeah the above code run but when i have parse xml value with special characters then error caused

Comment: I think there is no `FirstChild` in the XML file because  `macro2.php` is delivering a wrong file or empty file or something odd because of a wrong ID is submitted or something like that. Ensure that the loaded file is 100% correct.

Comment: You're generating an XML string without any escaping for the values you put in. Use an escaping function or even better use an XML API to generate the XML in PHP.

Comment: No FirstChild is there if their xml values are using no special characters then its working 100% file ...the actual problem problem was when i using special characters (&) these kind of error occurred ..  for eg : working names: manoj,jano etc ... error names: manoj&, jano- etc ...

Comment: Now i check and run my code again ID is absolutely correct and working fine but my problem is that i am unable ampersand (&) special character

Comment: I'm pretty sure your file is no valid XML. Test it in a XML validator like: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good article on your problem at [Techrepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/beware-of-the-ampersand-when-using-xml/) - quoting the necessary part:

> When the XML parser finds an ampersand in the XML data, it expects to find a symbol name and a semicolon following it. The symbol name provides a symbolic reference to another entity or character such as the ampersand, greater-than, and less-than characters. The symbolic name for greater-than is gt and for less-than is lt. To include a greater-than character in the XML data, you must use the following syntax: `&gt;`

If you already had the response from the PHP page then the solution to your problem is simply to do this:

```
strXml = VBA.Replace(strXml, "&", "&amp;")
```

But your issue is that you are using the `Load` method of the `DOMDocument` class and the PHP is emitting invalid XML. The PHP page should do this encoding for you - my guess is that it just queries some data store and slots it into an XML string an echos it without doing any validation on the values. Your `Load` method will not error, but the moment you want to parse the DOM, you get the problem.

Given you are already referencing the MSXML library, perhaps your option is to use the XMLHTTP class to get the response, do the replacement yourself, and then load it the DOMDocument using the `LoadXML` method. See the code below - it is not tested as I don't know the parameter for your URL:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TextXMLGetAndParse()

    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim objXhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim strXml As String
    Dim objXmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument

    Set objXhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set objXmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    ' do a XHR GET to your URL
    strUrl = "http://www.beamon.com/windows_application/macro2.php" + "?Id=" + Sheets(1).Range("D2")
    With objXhr
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .send
        strXml = .responseXML
    End With

    ' do the clean-up that the PHP page should do for you
    strXml = VBA.Replace(strXml, "&", "&amp;")

    ' load that XML to you DOMDOcument
    objXmlDoc.LoadXML strXml

    ' check values
    Debug.Print objXmlDoc.DocumentElement.Text
    Debug.Print objXmlDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.Text
    Debug.Print objXmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(1).Text
    Debug.Print objXmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(2).Text
    Debug.Print objXmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(3).Text

    ' clean up
    Set objXhr = Nothing
    Set objXhr = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: hai Robin i dont know how to use th  xml http class now i have fully changed and running on your code it shows error run time error 13 on this code   Set objXhr1 = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

Comment: Hi - yes there was an error in the code- I corrected it. You can try again?

Comment: hi robin thanks for your reply ! but again it seems error on the line: strXml = .responseXML   Run time error : 438 object doesn't support property or method

Comment: Hi - try `.responseText` instead ? If it works I will update the code. Unfortunately can't test this because don't have access to your URL with the PHP.

Comment: hi robin i change ur suggestions now again error occured for this line Debug.Print objXmlDoc.DocumentElement.text   run time error 91 object or with block variable not set ...

Comment: What happens if you Debug.Print strXml ? Can you post as a comment?

Comment: when i debug strXml = .responseXML into strXml = .responseText it will shows run time error '-2147483638 (80000000a)' The data necessary is complete this operation is not yet available

Comment: Ah sorry - another bug - the XMLHTTP call should not be Async - so I amend this line to `.Open "GET", strUrl, True` to `.Open "GET", strUrl, False`

Comment: hi thanks  robin :) its working  :) but how can i passing those values in excel cells ?

Comment: Good - finally we got it working ! To write out to the sheet you can use this: `Sheets(1).Range("T5") = objXmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(1).Text` or you can set `lists` to `objXmlDoc.DocumentElement` and use similar code to what you posted in your original question. Where I have used `Debug.Print something` you can just use `Sheets(1).Range("A1") = ...` HTH